# Jekyll Post Content Shown Twice

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I'm having an issue in my posts where any time I use header tags in markdown like:

`# Header Text`

or even a reference to an image in the markdown, all content after that header (or image) is shown twice: once immediately after `<body>` (as raw text), and a second time in the correct location where I reference `{{content}}` in my `post.html` file.

Any help would be super appreciated - I really can't figure this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out after having a look at [this issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2537)

If you have an un-closed tag in one of the files in your `_includes` folder, it will cause this to happen. So I went ahead and checked out each include file, and sure enough, I found that culprit.

Hope this helps others!